# Allow more decimals in price field - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I know that Magento provides the ability to use up to four decimals in the price field, but I need even more for certain products. The price could be for example 0.09857 and it is not up to me to round the price up, as the price comes from the original manufacturer and we need to stick to it precisely.

The price is just a base price that's going to be multiplied, as you might have guessed.

So is it possible to allow more decimals in the price field without hacking the core?